# cURL - Fall Back DNS

Tags: php, curl

I could be wrong, but looking at how cURL handles DNS it only looks up the first record. If that record can't be found it then fails and can't make the request.

Is there a way to make it look up the next record, as if it looks up the first one and it fails then the cURL request will fail - seems a bit silly to me, so I assume there is an easy way around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say you cannot (let's wait and see). But you can always grab the IP yourself and pass it to curl, as [this user comments](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102793) explains.

Comment: Which are the situations where there are multiple records and the first fails? Or do you mean a host with multiple A records where the first one you try to retrieve is offline? If that doesn't work, I'd file a bug report.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Thanks for the link, that's useful as a fallback... but as there are lots of cURL calls in our codebase I was hoping for a global solution - however looking unlikely!

Comment: @tripleee If the first DNS server can't be reached, it doesn't seem to them fallback to the second - it just flat out fails. Wonderful, right?

Comment: Shouldn't that be handled transparently by the resolver?

Comment: @tripleee No, the resolver has no way to know which IP addresses have working services on them.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? The resolver talks to DNS servers and should be able to fall back to a secondary server if the primary is not responding. If you get a reply from DNS indicating a server which is down, that's outside the domain of the resolver, and something Curl should deal with.